# Google Slides: is there a way to start a function when a specific slide is shown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I need to start a Google Apps Script function whenever a specific slide is shown.

For example: function `xyz()` should be called whenever slide #3 is opened.

Is it possible?

Comment: Presentation mode is not scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

There are [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) available for using via Apps Script, for Google Slides currently available:

- onOpen - when presentation opened in Google Slides *editor*
- onInstall - when Google Slides addon is installed
- time-driven (clock)

There are currectly no trigger for slide change in presentation mode, but there are related feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760981 you can "star" it.